# Detect password protected word file

Tags: c#, parsing, ms-word, netoffice

I am using "netoffice" library for extracting the text from word files. This should be automated process.

However, when the word file is password protected, the alert windows is shown so the user needs to enter the password. Because this is automated process, the user does not enters the password, and the program stops here.

How can I detect if the word file is password protected with "netoffice", and if this is not possible, how can I disable the alert windows from showing up?

I tried setting DisplayAlerts to WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code will help you skip password-protected files:

```
        int iFilesWithPassword = 0;
        Factory.Initialize();
        Application wordApplication = new NetOffice.WordApi.Application();

        try
        {
            // Attempt to open existing document. If document is not password protected then 
            // passwordDocument parameter is simply ignored. If document is password protected
            // then an error is thrown and caught by the catch clause the follows, unless 
            // password is equal to "#$nonsense@!"!                              
            Document newDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\Giorgos\Desktop\myNextFile.doc",
                                                                  confirmConversions: false,
                                                                  addToRecentFiles: false,
                                                                  readOnly: false,
                                                                  passwordDocument: "#$nonsense@!");



            // read text of document
            string text = newDocument.Content.Text;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Exception inner = e.InnerException;

            if (inner != null && inner.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = inner.InnerException;
                string sErrorMessage = inner.Message;

                if (sErrorMessage.Contains("The password is incorrect."))
                {
                    iFilesWithPassword++;
                }
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            // close word and dispose reference 
            wordApplication.Quit();
            wordApplication.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: I've made a console application in VS2012, using .NET Framework 4.0 along with NetOffice.dll, v1.6. If I ommit the passwordDocument argument I get the password prompt dialog as well. If I add the passwordDocument argument then no dialog is shown and an exception is thrown.

Comment: Not sure if [programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2096420)'s comment needs deleting given the accepted answer status of this answer, but I can confirm that the VBS version of this script does work as [giorgos-betsos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2149718) suggests.