# Check if a Word Document is password protected without opening it

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, password-protection

I'm using the Microsoft Office Interop namespace in order to password protect Word documents. 
I first create an instance of Word as a background process and gather the list of Word documents I want to protect. The issue I have is that when the application gets to an already secure document it opens with a prompt for the set password. After dismissing this it runs through the rest of the documents with the instance of Word now in the foreground.

I would like to skip past the previously protected documents. My code is currently as follows:

```
    private void Protect_Word(FileInfo file)
    {
            Word.Document doc = wrd.Documents.Open(file.FullName);
            if (!doc.HasPassword)
            { 
                doc.Password = this.passwordBox.Text;
                doc.Save();

            }
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)doc).Close(0);
    }
```

The problem with this setup is that the password for a document is being asked for before I can call HasPassword. Is there a way I can programatically check the document for a password prior to actually opening it?

Comment: Mmm, there would be a way if we're dealing with docx/docm documents that get encrypted when password protected. In that case, it's not possible to access the zip package due to the file encryption. So your code could first try to open the zip package. If it can, then the document has not yet been password protected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347513/how-to-detect-if-a-word-document-is-password-protected-before-uploading-the-file
[How to detect if a Word document is password protected before uploading the file to server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347513/how-to-detect-if-a-word-document-is-password-protected-before-uploading-the-file)
maybe this can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect password protected word file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235417/detect-password-protected-word-file)

Comment: Not trying to one up the above comment, but believe an easier and faster way to check for password protected files is in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235417) answer. For people getting to this page about this problem in VBA/S scripts, the following is the version in the former, which is easily adaptable to the latter. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=148962 . Though I would suggest checking for err.number=5408 (what gets thrown with a wrong password, when protected), rather than using any err.number to determine that file is password protected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a Word document is password protected before uploading the file to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347513/how-to-detect-if-a-word-document-is-password-protected-before-uploading-the-file)

Answer (score 2):

Also experiencing this problem ...
I came up with the "dirty solution" - pass invalid password for "Word" (or Excel) and if the document with a password, WINWORD.EXE will process this option will try to apply to the document, the password does not match, will generate a COM exception, we catch the exception and understand that document WITH A PASSWORD! Otherwise, if the document does not have a password, the Word processor itself will ignore the transmitted password (I understood this after checking it experimentally ... )

```
        Word.Application app = null;
        Word.Documents docs = null;
        try
        {
            app = new Word.Application();
            app.Visible = false;
            docs = app.Documents;
            // перебираем список файлов
            for (int i = 0; i < listFilesWord.Count; i++)
            {
                Word.Document doc = null;
                try
                {
                    doc = docs.Open(
                        listFilesWord[i].FullName,
                        Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument,
                        (object)false,
                        Type.Missing,
                        " ",
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        (object)false,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        (object)true,
                        Type.Missing);
                    doc.Save();
                    doc.Close();
                }
                catch (COMException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
                }
            }
            app.Quit();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (docs != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docs);
            if (app != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you say "without opening it" you must mean "without opening it **in Word**" (because you must inspect the file contents which requires opening it **on the file level.**)

It looks as if the docx file format, like others, has an identifying signature at the beginning, namely the zip file signature `50 4b 03 04`. (Are there endianness issues? I'm on little-endian Intel.) This probably reflects the choice made by MS to store office documents as an XML file collection in a standard zip file.

When the file is encrypted though the first bytes change to something else (in my case to `d0 cf 11 e0` which the [File Signature Database](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=D0CF11E0A1B11AE1&mode=SIG) identifies as an Access project file for some reason).

This just *may* be sufficient for telling "normal" from encrypted Word documents, but you may want to do more research first, both by parsing the relevant documentation and by cross checking a typical set of documents from the source which you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar information and couldn't found a straight answer.
I managed to find a good solution for two problems using vb .net:

1. Detect if a docx is password protected to open file:
   *msgbox(documentName.haspassword.tostring)*
   This will give you true or false for the password protection
2. SaveAs a password protected document to a document without password:
   *documentName.password("known password") = ""*
   This will save a copy of the open document without the password