# How to detect .doc password protection

Tags: php

The following answer allows to detect password protected `.docx` files, after porting it to PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14347730/1794894

```
$content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($absolutePath));
if (mb_substr($content, 0, 2) == "ÐÏ") {

    # DOC/XLS 2007+
    $start = str_replace("\x00", " ", mb_substr($content, 0, 2000));
    if (mb_strstr($start, 'E n c r y p t e d P a c k a g e') !== false) {
        return true;
    }

    if ($extension == 'doc') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

How to also make a `.doc` specific check? Do `.doc` files also have a specific byte sequence? Or is it enough to only rely on the `ÐÏ` check at the first two characters of the file?

Or is the character at position 0x20B always equal to 0x13 in case of a password protected `.doc`?

Comment: TL;DR but that `E n c r y p t e d P a c k a g e` string looks weird. I suspect you want to search for `EncryptedPackage` using a proper encoding (UTF-16 or something).

Comment: The `ÐÏ` at the beginning of the file indicates a format that uses an OLE2 wrapper, such as .doc, .xls, .ppt

Comment: You'll have to ask the "dll":  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.dll [Document::HasPassword Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.haspassword.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1). using: PHP [COM Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php).

Comment: this is a good example of it: [excel](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php#19688)

Comment: Are you talking about DOC or DOCX files? `.docx` are ZIP files containing meta information and content. Unzip the file and look for a settings.xml which should contain information about the encryption.

Comment: @DanFromGermany the `.docx` cannot be opened as zip if it is encrypted. That is why the weird looking `E n c r y p t e d P a c k a g e` is in the source.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it based on the C# example from the post in the question.

We can not make use of a COM object, most servers do not run MS Word.

See Gist snippet: https://gist.github.com/rvanlaak/06ca1b65658a91240362

Comment: hi Rvanlaak, could you give me some advice on how to detect xls, ppt, pptx encrypted file?  The script in your gist snippet only work fine for doc, docx, xlsx file. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this...

```
<?php
  $word=new COM("word.application") or die("Cannot create Word object");
  $word->Visible=false;
  $word->WindowState=2;
  $word->DisplayAlerts=false;
  $doc = $word->Document->Open("/yourFile.doc");
  $passwordProtect = $doc->Document->HasPassword;//true or false
  $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
  $word->Quit();
  $word->Release();
  $word=null;
?>
```

I can't test this code, hope it helps...