# Identifying encrypted Word docs with perl

Tags: perl, encryption, ms-word

I have a series of Word docs that require a password to decode and would like to be able to identify them as having a password among a series of non-encrypted Word docs.

I've followed much of the guidance provided by this stackoverflow link:

[How to detect if a Word document is password protected before uploading the file to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347513/how-to-detect-if-a-word-document-is-password-protected-before-uploading-the-file/14347730#14347730)

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
 sub _is_encrypted_doc {
   my ($data) = @_;

 if (_is_office_doc($data)) {
     if ($data =~ /(?:<encryption xmlns)/i) {
       return 1;
     }
     if (index($data, "\x13") == 523) {
       return 1;
     }
     if (index($data, "\x2f") == 532) {
       return 1;
     }
     if (index($data, "\xfe") == 520) {
       return 1;
     }
     my $tdata = substr $data, 2000;
     $tdata =~ s/\\0/ /g;
     if (index($tdata, "E n c r y p t e d P a c k a g e") > -1) {
       return 1;
     }
   }
 }
```

However, my code doesn't appear to identify all variations we've received. I've uploaded one such file here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uk51fixkc12aove/g9kfak164.docx?dl=0

Use "NZlttUtz" to decode. I'm relatively new at this, so I hoped someone could guide me here. Is there more comprehensive code already available to do this?

Comment: what does the `_is_office_doc`? because your file contains the `<encryption xmlns)` so it should be identified by the 1st rule.

Comment: Can you tell me what method you used to read the file to determine it contains the `<encryption xmlns)` ?

Comment: `xxd g9kfak164.docx | less` so again the question. What doing the `_is_office_doc` method?

Comment: I've uploaded the full code I've been given here https://pastebin.com/UebVFnJ9 I believe the issue is with the markers that are used to detect these files is no longer accurate for these strong encryption word docs. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see in the link you reference, generally files beginning with the ÐÏ prefix are protected, & I've not found any unprotected word documents that do begin with that prefix. So unless you need to distinguish between e.g. Excel and Word and which version the documents are (which might be better handled via file ext), you can simply test for files beginning with Ð.

```
use Fcntl qw(:seek);

my($fh, $FILE, $byte_position, $byte_value);

$FILE      = "path/to/file";
$byte_position = 0;

open($fh, "<", $FILE)
  || die "can't open $FILE: $!";

binmode($fh)
  || die "can't binmode $FILE";

sysseek($fh, $byte_position, SEEK_CUR)  # NB: 0-based
  || die "couldn't see to byte $byte_position in $FILE: $!";

sysread($fh, $byte_value, 1) == 1
  || die "couldn't read byte from $FILE: $!";

if (ord($byte_value) == 208){
  return 1;
}
else {
  return 0;
}
```

i.e. Read first byte of file to see if it is D0hex (ASCII Ð), if it is return 1 for protected document, otherwise return 0.

Comment: I think you mean `if ($data eq 208) {` ? It otherwise prints `Argument "<D0>" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`. It also never equals 208, and always just returns 0. Other ideas?

Comment: This still doesn't work for me :-( It always just returns 0 in a loop for every character in the file. Printing $data shows that it is indeed "<D0>" (zero), but it never matches...

Comment: Ok. Lets try a different approach then. (Answer edited)